# a confusing case in Ruby MetaProgramming

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming

I'm a start learner about Ruby MetaProgramming. when practicing my code in irb, I met this problem.

```
class A; end
a = A.new
b = class << a; self; end

b.instance_eval { def foo; puts 'foo'; end }
# => works for b.foo

b.instance_eval { define_method :bar do; puts 'bar'; end }
# => WHY this one works for a.bar rather than b.bar
```

The last code fragment confused me.

---

Thanks for your specific answers, but maybe I didn't explain my confusion clearly. What I'm really trying to understand is why `define_method` behaves so differently in these cases, here:

```
class A
  def foo1
    p 'foo1 from A'
  end 

  define_method :bar1 do
    p 'bar1 from A'
  end 
end

a = A.new
a.foo1 # => 'foo1 from A'
a.bar1 # => 'bar1 from A'


a.instance_eval { def foo2; p 'foo2 from a.metaclass'; end }
a.foo2 # => 'foo2 from a.metaclass'
a.instance_eval { define_method :bar2 do; p 'bar2 from a.metaclass'; end }
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for #<A:0x000000016a2e70>

aa = class << a; self; end
aa.instance_eval { def foo3; p 'foo3 from a.metaclass.metaclass'; end }
aa.foo3 # => 'foo3 from a.metaclass.metaclass'
aa.instance_eval { define_method :bar3 do; p 'bar3 from a.metaclass.metaclss'; end }
aa.bar3 # => NoMethodError: undefined method `bar3' for #<Class:#<A:0x000000016a2e70>>
a.bar3 # => 'bar3 from a.metaclass.metaclss'
```

I know that this doesn't come up in day-to-day coding, but I want to make my mind clear.

---

make a conclusion:

```
aa = class << a; self; end 

aa.instance_eval { def foo; puts 'foo..'; end }

# defines a singleton-method for aa
aa.foo # => 'foo...'


aa.instance_eval { define_method :bar do; puts 'bar..'; end }
# equals
aa.class_eval { def bar; puts 'bar..'; end }

# both define a singleton-method for a,
# as define_method and class_eval both define instance_method
a.bar # => 'bar...'
```

Comment: About class_eval and instance_eval, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866047/dynamically-creating-class-method/13870694#13870694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to all other comments :

[from the Pickaxe] The method Object#instance_eval lets you set self to be some arbitrary object, evaluates the code in a block with [self], and then resets self.
And Module#define_method : Defines an instance method in the receiver [self, which must be a (anonymous) Class or Module].

```
singleton_class_of_object_a = aa = class << a; self; end
aa.instance_eval { def foo3; puts "foo3 from singleton class of a, self=#{self}"; end }
aa.foo3 # => foo3 from singleton class of a, self=#<Class:#<A:0x007fc2e4049e68>>
aa.instance_eval do
    puts "about to define_method :bar3 in self=#{self}"
    define_method :bar3 do; puts "bar3 from singleton class of a, self=#{self}"; end
end # => about to define_method :bar3 in self=#<Class:#<A:0x007fc2e4049e68>>
a.bar3 # => bar3 from singleton class of a, self=#<A:0x007fc2e4049e68>
```

`define_method :bar3` is executed in the context of singleton_class_of_object_a (an anonymous class, see below), thus defines an instance method of that class, hence bar3 becomes a singleton method of a. As already said in my previous answer, it is equivalent to defining directly on the object :

```
def a.bar4; puts 'bar4 from singleton class of a' end
a.bar4 # => bar4 from singleton class of a

p a.singleton_methods.sort # => [:bar3, :bar4, :foo2]
p a.methods(false).sort # => [:bar3, :bar4, :foo2]
```

After `a = A.new`, the field class of instance **a** points to class **A**.
With `class << a` or `def a.bar4`, Ruby creates an anonymous class, the field class of instance **a** now points to this **anonymous class**, and from there to **A**.
Methods defined in this context with `def` or `define_method` go into the methods table of the anonymous class.

Comment: Thanks for remind me of this, 'Module#define_method : Defines an instance method in the receiver'. I've got it, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

because in your case `def foo` acts as `def self.foo`
and `define_method :bar` acts as `def bar`.

this happens cause **`instance_eval` creates class methods**.

your code is identical to:

```
class << a
  def self.foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

so the `foo` method is defined inside `a`'s eigen class
and the `bar` method is defined inside `a` itself.

if you need `a.foo` to work use `class_eval` instead.

it will work cause **`class_eval` creates instance methods**:

```
b.class_eval { def foo; puts 'foo'; end }
a.foo
# => foo
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still don't get that why `def foo` acts as `def self.foo`

Comment: @ifyouseewendy, the main point here is that `instance_eval` actually creates class methods. `class_eval` instead creates instance methods. that's why your `def foo` is equivalent to `def self.foo`. try `class_eval { def foo ` and you'll get `a.foo` working

Comment: `a.instance_eval { define_method` will fail cause `a` is a instance and does not respond to `define_method`. `aa.instance_eval { define_method :bar3` is defining `:bar3` inside `a`, cause **`instance_eval` creates class methods**.

Comment: if you need `aa.bar3`, use `class_eval` instead: `aa.class_eval { define_method :bar3`, cause **`class_eval` creates instance methods**.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.instance_eval { def foo; puts 'foo'; end }
b.instance_eval { puts "self in b.instance_eval block=#{self}" }
#=> self in b.instance_eval block=#<Class:#<A:0x007fe3c204d000>>
b.foo #=> foo
```

You are defining a method in the singleton class of a single instance of A. It looks pretty complex. Rather define a singleton method directly on the instance :

```
cat = String.new("cat")
def cat.speak
    'miaow'
end
cat.speak #=> "miaow" 
cat.singleton_methods #=> ["speak"]
```

The `class <<` notation such as

```
singleton_class_of_A = eigenclass_of_A = class << A; self; end
```

is usually used to defined "class methods" (actually singleton methods of A), or instances variables of the class :

```
class B
    class << self
        def my_class_method_of_B
            puts "my_class_method_of_B"
        end
        @my_first_variable_of_class_B = 123
        attr_accessor :my_second_variable_of_class_B
    end
end

B.my_class_method_of_B
print 'singleton methods of B : '
p B.singleton_methods
print 'instance variables of B : '
p B.instance_variables
print 'class variables of B : '
p B.class_variables
print '"singleton variables" of B : '
class << B; p instance_variables end
```

Output :

```
my_class_method_of_B
singleton methods of B : [:my_class_method_of_B, :my_second_variable_of_class_B, :my_second_variable_of_class_B=]
instance variables of B : []
class variables of B : []
"singleton variables" of B : [:@my_first_variable_of_class_B]
```

As you can see, this matter is not easy, you may wish to have a look at http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby