# Ruby instance_eval on a class with attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor, class-eval, instance-eval

I understand the basic difference between `instance_eval` and `class_eval`. What I've discovered though when playing around is something strange involving `attr_accessor`. Here's an example:

```
A = Class.new
A.class_eval{ attr_accessor :x }

a = A.new
a.x = "x"
a.x
=> "x"  # ... expected

A.instance_eval{ attr_accessor :y }

A.y = "y"
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `y=' for A:Class

a.y = "y"
=> "y"      # WHATTT?
```

How is it that:

1. the instance_eval didn't at the accessor onto our A class (object)
2. it then in fact added it onto instances of A?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first, your understanding (or intuition) is correct, methods defined inside `#instance_eval` and `#class_eval` are not the same

```
A = Class.new

A.instance_eval { def defined_in_instance_eval; :instance_eval; end }
A.class_eval { def defined_in_class_eval; :class_eval; end }

A.new.defined_in_class_eval # => :class_eval
A.defined_in_instance_eval # => :instance_eval
```

*a side note: while `self` is the same in both `instance_eval` and `class_eval`, the **default definee** is different, see http://yugui.jp/articles/846*

What really does the trick is `Module#attr_accessor` itself, look at its definition:
http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_method.c#620

it does not use `def`, it does not read context, `self` or a default definee. It just "manually" inserts methods into a module. That's why the result is counterintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

For the difference between `class_eval` and `instance_eval`, see [Dynamically creating class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866047/dynamically-creating-class-method/13870694#13870694)

```
class A; end
A.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :x
    def barx; end
    define_method :foox do; end
end

print 'A.instance_methods  : '; p A.instance_methods(false).sort
print 'A.singleton_methods : '; p A.singleton_methods

class B; end
B.instance_eval do
    attr_accessor :y
    def bary; end
    define_method :fooy do; end
end

print 'B.instance_methods  : '; p B.instance_methods(false).sort
print 'B.singleton_methods : '; p B.singleton_methods

class C; end
singleton_class = class << C; self end
singleton_class.instance_eval do
    attr_accessor :z
    def barz; puts 'where is barz ?' end
    define_method :fooz do; end
end

print 'C.instance_methods  : '; p C.instance_methods(false).sort
print 'C.singleton_methods : '; p C.singleton_methods

print 'singleton_class.barz : '; singleton_class.barz
print 'singleton_class.methods  : '; p singleton_class.methods(false)
```

Output (ruby 1.8.6):

```
A.instance_methods  : ["barx", "foox", "x", "x="]
A.singleton_methods : []
B.instance_methods  : ["fooy", "y", "y="]
B.singleton_methods : ["bary"]
C.instance_methods  : []
C.singleton_methods : ["z", "z=", "fooz"]
singleton_class.barz : where is barz ?
singleton_class.methods  : ["barz"]
```

As you can see with B, despite the fact that instance_eval usually creates singleton methods, obviously `attr_accessor` and `define_method` force the definition of instance methods.

Comment: man that's messed up. Great examples. @Daniel_Vartanov's answer actually explains why `attr_accessor` doesn't apply to self, but this is a great way of illustrating exactly what happens with each type of method def'n. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
A.singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor :y }
A.y = 'y'
A.y
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `attr_accessor` is a class method such that, when called in the **body** of a **class**, then accessor methods are defined on the **instances** of that class.

When you do `A.class_eval{...}`, you are calling it within the **body** of a **class** `A`, so its **instances** such as `a` are assigned accessors.

When you do `A.instance_eval{...}`, you calling it within a **non-body** of a **class** `A`, so its instances are not assigned accessors.

If you do `Class.class_eval{attr_accessor :z}`, then you are calling it withing the **body** of a **class** `Class`, so its **instances** such as `A` will be assigned accessors: `A.z = ...`.