# What is this line of Ruby code doing?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [class << self idiom in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)

I was wondering what this code is doing. I don't understated this one line. I know what `attr_accessor` is.

```
class User
  class << self; attr_accessor :base_uri end
  ....
....
...
```

Comment: See `singleton_class.instance_eval do` in the second part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13861177#13861177 and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428531/ruby-instance-eval-on-a-class-with-attr-accessor/14431130#14431130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will see `class << self` used often in Ruby. The easiest way to understand what it does is to think of it as (almost) equivalent to this:

```
class Abc
   self.attr_accessor ...
end
```

Which is basically the same as this:

```
Abc.class.attr_accessor ...
```

But you really can't do either of those because:

```
> Abc.class.attr_accessor :blah
NoMethodError: private method `attr_accessor' called for Class:Class
```

So to get around it you'd have to do:

```
> Abc.class.send(:attr_accessor, :blah)
```

Or:

```
class Abc
  self.send(:attr_accessor, :blah)
end
```

That's where the `<< self` construct comes in since it gives you access to these private methods. You are basically operating directly in "self-space".

Similarly when you see:

```
class Abc
   class << self
     def foo
     end
   end
end
```

It's just the same as saying:

```
class Abc
   def self.foo
   end
end
```

Which will define a class method, just like the code in your question will define a class-level attr_accessor.

**EDIT**

As for a less complicated way - Ruby doesn't really by default have a method that is able to create class-level attr_accessors. That's why you have to use the `<< self` trick.

But Rails does define a method that does something similar without having to use `<< self`. In Rails you have [`cattr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor):

```
class Abc
   cattr_accessor :blah
end

Abc.blah = 123
Abc.blah
>> 123
```

Answer (score 1):

This let define an instance variable in the class context.

See the code:

```
class User
  class << self; attr_accessor :base_uri end
  @base_uri = "aaa";
end

p User.base_uri # will output "aaa"
```

Comment: hmm? so if I didn't want to write it like what I posted, was there any less complicated way of writing the same thing?